# How to modify/clear/delete a QWidget from a QGridLayout ? - Python, PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, grid

I wish to have a QGridLayout containing some informations that can be dynamicaaly changed. However, as it is, it will only superimpose the different informations on top of the previous one instead of replacing it. Surprisingly I couldn't find a method to remove or clean or such a widget from a grid. So what, can't it be dynamically changed ?...

Here is an example of code :

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
    QLabel
)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("QGridLayout Example")
        # Create a QGridLayout instance
        self.buttonA = QPushButton("A")
        self.buttonB = QPushButton("B")
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        # Add widgets to the layout
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonA, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonB, 0, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("C"), 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("D"), 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("E"), 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("F"), 2, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("G"), 2, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("H"), 2, 2)
        # Set the layout on the application's window
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        
        self.buttonA.clicked.connect(self.change_label)
        self.buttonB.clicked.connect(self.change_label2)
        
    def change_label(self):
        self.label = QLabel("Hello")
    self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        
    def change_label2(self):
        self.label = QLabel("Bonjour")
    self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When one clicks on button A, I want to have displayed in box (0,0) "Hello". Then if one clicks on button B, I want to replace the text "Hello" with "Bonjour". However I can only have one text on top of the other which is obviously hardly readable then.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Just create that label without any text in the `__init__` and add it to the layout, then use `self.label.setText('Hello')` in the function.

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much ! By any chance, do you know if there is a way to clear a box from a QGridLayer ? In the case where my QWidget is not a QLabel but something more troublesome ?

Comment: It depends on what you need to do, but, generally, you can just `hide()` the widget if you then want to `show()` it again (or use `setVisible()`).

Comment: So nothing is to be done if you want to replace the wigdet with another ? Like if I have a picture and want to change it for example ?

Comment: If you want to replace the image, then just call `setPixmap()`. As said, it depends on what you need to do, there are many possible approaches available, we cannot cover all of them (especially in comments for an unrelated question). If you have a specific problem, then ask a specific question about *that* problem.

Comment: [QLayout.replaceWidget()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#replaceWidget).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
    QLabel
)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("QGridLayout Example")
        # Create a QGridLayout instance
        self.label = QLabel("Show text here")

        self.buttonA = QPushButton("A")
        self.buttonB = QPushButton("B")
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        # Add widgets to the layout
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonA, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonB, 0, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("C"), 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("D"), 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("E"), 1, 2)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("F"), 2, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("G"), 2, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton("H"), 2, 2)
        # Set the layout on the application's window
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        
        self.buttonA.clicked.connect(self.change_label)
        self.buttonB.clicked.connect(self.change_label2)
        
    def change_label(self):
        self.label.setText("Hello")
        
    def change_label2(self):
        self.label.setText("Bonjour")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```