# Is there a way I can delete a Column in a Grid Layout PYQT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I have a table of 4 columns and I would like to know if there is a way I can delete or update all the values in one of the columns at the press of a button, as I am trying to make an application that will update values in each column from a web page. I am able to add to the existing items but if the value is different then it just goes over the top of it.

Comment: This seems quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379290/how-to-modify-clear-delete-a-qwidget-from-a-qgridlayout-python-pyqt). Besides, consider QTableWidget.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.